# Convert image boundary to polygon geometry in earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have imported Hansen image for global forest change and clipped it for a specific region(India). Then using the code below I extracted the areas where tree cover is greater then 25%.

```
var treeCanopyCover = hansen.clip(india).select('treecover2000');
var greater25 = treeCanopyCover.gte(25);
var treeCover_greater25 = treeCanopyCover.updateMask(greater25);



var treeCanopyCoverVis = {
  min: 25.0,
 max: 100.0,
palette:
  ['3d3d3d', '080a02', '080a02', '080a02', '106e12', '37a930', '03ff17'],

};


Map.setCenter(82.5, 23.5);
 Map.addLayer(treeCover_greater25, treeCanopyCoverVis, 'Tree Canopy Cover');
```

Since the output is an image I can't appply 'filterBounds' to filter an image Collection over this area.Is there any way that I can convert this to polygon geometry so that I can filter my image collection over these forest areas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `reduceToVectors`, but for a large area as India that would possibly run out of computation.
I think it is better if you apply the geometry of India to filter the image collection on. You can then use `updateMask` to masked out all the pixels that are not forest in 2000 based on the Hansen dataset:

```
 // get landsat 5 images (as an example, could be any image collection)
 var landsat5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA")
  // filter bounds on the geometry of India
  .filterBounds(india)
  // filter date on the similar year as the tree cover (not necesarry)
  .filterDate('2000','2001');

// Mask out all the pixels that are tree cover
var maskedLandsat5 = landsat5.map(function(image){
  return image.updateMask(greater25);
});
```

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8a34a4028b7d662eef850edc367354fa)

Comment: But I also need to print a chart showing monthly mean NDVI variation in forest regions of India. So, what will I specify as the 'region' while printing chart if I can't get the forest regions as 'geometry'. Will the result be accurate if I give 'region' as whole 'India'?

Comment: Yes give as region the whole of India in that chart. All pixels that are masked won't be displayed in the chart

Comment: Thank you so much!